# What are the lossy audio formats supported by java?

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, audio-processing, audioformat

I am trying to implement a client server RTP Streaming player. Currently I am using .wav format and its working fine in my scenario. But the issue with .wav format is that it consumes alot of memory and I want some more compressed audio format which consumes lesser amount of Memory space. Lossy Audio format in this regards would make sense. 
I would be grateful if I could get the help in this regards that which format should I use. Whats the compression rate as compare to .wav. Is it supported by Java or not(As I have tried using mp3 but faced alot of difficulty in converting it into Raw PCM format, even though I succeeded in conversion, when Raw PCM was sent to the client side in RTP packet. The audio received was complete noise.)

Comment: All audio formats are supported in java. Java is a programming language.

Comment: @szatmary I know that java is a programming language but their some formats that Java directly support meanwhile there are some formats which require Java plugins such as mp3pi, tritonus or jlayer in case of mp3 audio format. 
I just want to know that which formate would be suitable other than .wav, the condition prior to this is that audio formate should be directly supported by Java. 
Any lossy audio formate would do great.